# Cycle Backwards Through Slides

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have the following jQuery:

```
            var $active = $('#slideshow li.active');

            if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow li:last');

            // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
            var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
                : $('#slideshow li:first');

            // uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

            // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
            // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
            // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


            $active.addClass('last-active');

            $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
                .addClass('active')
                .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500, function() {
                    $active.removeClass('active last-active');
                });
```

How do I modify this so that I can cycle backwards?

I've got this far, but It doesn't cycle back to the last element from the first. There's got to be something rather simple I'm missing but I really just can't put my finger on it.

```
            var $active = $('#slideshow li.active');

            if ( $active.length == 0 ){ $active = $('#slideshow li:last');}

            // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
            var $next =  0 ? $active.prev()
                : $('#slideshow li:first');

            // uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

            // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
            // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
            // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


            $active.addClass('last-active');

            $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
                .addClass('active')
                .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500, function() {
                    $active.removeClass('active last-active');
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currrent solution checks to see if there is an element after the `active` element. We'll change this to see if there is one *before* the `active` element. The original fallback is to select the first list-item within `#slideshow`. We will instead select the last.

```
var $next = $active.prev().length ? $active.prev() : $('#slideshow li:last');
```

If you're not familiar with the ternary operator, it's essentially the same thing as writing an if-statement:

```
// If there are previous elements
if ( $active.prev().length > 0 ) {
    // The next element will be the previous element
    $next = $active.prev();
} else {
    // The next element will be the last list item in #slideshow
    $next = $("#slideshow li:last");
}
```

Comment: @JohnathanSampson thank you very much! I knew it was something like this but I was really struggling to read the jQuery. I like to try and iterpret it into English but was jsut struggling to read exactly what the code did.

Comment: How exactly does it read
    if ( $active.prev().length)
?

Does it ask if there is a length?

Comment: @AntonioMoore "If we have previous elements." The `.length` portion counts the `.prev()` portion. So it's like asking "How many .prev() do we have?" If there aren't any, `0` will be the value, and this is considered *falsy* in JavaScript. jQuery returns 1 element with `.prev()`, so we expect `.length` to be `1`. If it's not, we know we don't have any previous element.

Comment: Ah now I understand! Very Much appreciated Jonathan! You've just helped me finish my first jQuery plugin!!